# C++ LNK2019 Error, lib has been added to linker

Tags: c++, lib

First time I actually started writing a project in C++, for purposes. I'd like to include the TNL library.

The header files are already defined correctly and can use them. For the linker, when i try to use a function that's in the lib file it still gives me a LNK2019 error. The lib is added to the linker.

Error message example:
[image]

Here are some screenshots with the paths. I 'think' that i've put them correctly but could definitely looked over something.

Additional Dependencies:
[image]

Additional Library Directories
[image]

Actual Library Lib's are located at:
[image]

I'm probably tunnel-visioning on something. But I'm stuck right now and I'm clueless.

Comment: Is the library compiled for your version of Visual Studio? Side note: If you switch from the Error List tab to the Output tab you may get a different and more explicit error message. The raw text can be much more helpful than the abbreviated version you see on the Error List AND it's plain text so you can cut and paste it verbatim into the question instead of futzing around with screenshots.

Comment: Dear, I have the source of the library and I compiled it on the 2017 platform. I believe it's on 2010 standard. Anyway. Raw text doesn't give me any more feedback than the error list. Still the same.

Comment: Bummer. Going to have to leave this to folks who know the Visual Studio tool chain better.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582(v=vs.85).aspx and scroll down to where it tell you the lib you need.

Comment: Thank you ninja. Didn't notice this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unresolved symbol is `_closesocket@4`, which should probably resolve to [closesocket()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582(v=vs.85).aspx) from the Windows sockets library.  Try adding "Ws2_32.lib" to the Additional Dependencies line.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed most of the unsolved symbols errors I had.